# Rules for the use of angle brackets in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

What are the general rules that dictate when, where, how and why angle brackets, i.e. `<...>`, should be used in TypeScript?

While I think I understand many individual uses of these brackets, I have a hard time seeing general patterns for their use: they sometimes seem to be prepended before things, sometimes appended after things; sometimes they are used for generics, sometimes for specific types; sometimes they appear where I might have expected the colon syntax to be used.

I'd like to have a concise but exhaustive/universal explanation of what the brackets mean, their exact syntax, when they should be used, when they *shouldn't* be used, etc.

Comment: Couldn't you give some examples of angle brackets use you don't understand? What you mean under _appear after things_ and _where colon syntax expected to be used_?

Angle brackets _before things_ is possibly type casting? _After thnigs_ with `type parameter` - is defing generic type.

Comment: @n.turakulov, re: before/after, here are examples directly from the TypeScript spec: angle brackets before something: `var circle = <Circle> shape;`, angle brackets after something: `var x: KeyValuePair<number, string> = [10, "ten"];`, angle brackets alone (i.e. neither before nor after): `var <ClassName> = (function () {...`. When I say "colon syntax", I mean that sometimes you see `<string>` and sometimes you see `... : string`. Thx for the specific explanations you provided but I'm looking for an exhaustive (but simple and concise) set of rules.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

With questions like this, I'd recommend reading [the spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md), especially the Grammar section. Syntax like `< something >` is used in

1. **Type Parameters**

   - Defined as `< TypeParameterList >` in [section 3.6.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md#361-type-parameter-lists)
   - Used with declarations and call signatures of classes, interfaces, functions and more

     ```
     function heat<T>(food: T): T { return food; }
               //^^^^^ Type parameter list

     class Pizza<T, E extends Cheese> { toppingA: T; toppingB: E }
              //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type parameter list
     ```
2. **Type Arguments**

   - Defined as `< TypeArgumentList >` in [section 3.6.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md#362-type-argument-lists)
   - Used with references to generic types and calls to generic functions

     ```
     var pizza: Pizza<Pepperoni, Mozzarella>;
                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type argument list
     pizza = heat<{ toppingA: Pepperoni, toppingB: Mozzarella}>(ingredients) 
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type argument list
     ```

     **Update 2018-07-01:**
     As of version 2.9, generic type arguments can also be used in [JSX elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements) and [tagged templates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-generic-tagged-templates).

     ```
      <MenuItem<Pizza> toppings={[Pepperoni, Mozzarella]} />
             //^^^^^^^ Type argument list

      const ratingHtml = escapeUserInput<string | number> `Customer ${feedback.customer.username} rated this pizza with <b>${feedback.rating}</b>/10!`
                                       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type argument list
     ```
3. **Type Assertions**

   - Defined and used as `< Type > UnaryExpression` where [UnaryExpression comes from EcmaScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-operators) in [section 4.16](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions)

     ```
     var ingredients = {
         toppingA: new Pepperoni,
         toppingB: <Mozzarella> fridge.takeSomeCheese()
                 //^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type assertion
     };
     ```
4. **JSX expressions (when enabled)**

   - Not documented in the spec, but should follow the [the syntax of JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/#syntax), which is basically an expression like

     ```
     <JSXElementName JSXAttributes(optional)> JSXChildren(optional) </JSXElementName>
     ```

     or

     ```
     <JSXElementName JSXAttributes(optional) />
     ```

Comment: It is worth noting that the preferred syntax for a type-assertion is now `UnaryExpression as Type`, as the former is ambiguous in `.tsx` files.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for laying out the use cases for angle brackets. Thanks also for pointing me to the relevant sections of the spec, especially the Grammar section. I had begun reading the spec but had gotten bogged down and hadn't noticed how concisely that section answered my question.

Comment: @AndrewWillems Glad to help. Note that the spec I linked points to a specific version of it so that the links in the answer won't die in the future. You, however, should probably use the [newest version](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md).

Comment: @noppa do you know where we could find the Spec for version 2 of TypeScript?

Comment: @Ciwan I couldn't find one either. Their [What's new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript) document lists the new features quite nicely, but I do hope they update the [doc directory](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/doc) soon too.

Comment: I couldn't find "the spec" anywhere on https://www.typescriptlang.org/ is it just me or is it not linked anywhere on the site. I was so confused. It seems like the website is supposed to be the definitive information source for the language but I don't see a link to [the spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md) that you provided anywhere. It's much more useful than the reference section on the website. The docs on the website aren't clear about the meaning or syntax of anything.

Comment: @ADJenks Unfortunately, I don't think the TS team has published/updated a spec for the language for a few years now, and don't seem to be intending to do so. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15711#issuecomment-661290678 I guess now the "spec" is some combination of the implementation, the Handbook, and the release notes.

Comment: That's spec-tacular 

Answer (score 2):

They are used for multiple, far too semantically distinct expressions for one to formulate a common use case over them. It also depends on context, much like curly brackets. As you probably know, angle brackets in pairs are used:

- As a deprecated syntax for type-assertions
- For manually specifying generic type parameters
- For declaring elements in `.tsx`

When not in a `.tsx` file, angle brackets in pairs are virtually always the indication of the presence of a generic type parameter. One might formulate a system of expressions as such (which is probably the closest you can get):

- When in the context of a type definition, type annotation, method invocation, or class declaration, angle brackets denote a *generic type parameter*
- When in the context of a TSX element, angle brackets denote an element as transpiled by a TSX/JSX compiler

Comment: Thx for your response. Re your 1st sentence: with all due respect, it MUST be possible to formulate such a description. I don't know if you saw my question update. In it I show how, even tho curly braces in JavaScript have multiple, semantically distinct use cases, I was able to fairly clearly lay out all of them in 4 short sentences with 2 5-point lists. In fact, the rest of your answer is, I believe, part way (tho not yet the whole way?) to giving me what I'm looking for. (For the record, I don't yet understand .tsx files, React, JSX, etc.)