# What does enclosing a class in angle brackets "<>" mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, brackets

I am very new to TypeScript and I am loving it a lot, especially how easy it is to do OOP in Javascript. I am however stuck on trying to figure out the semantics when it comes to using angle brackets.

From their docs, I have seen several examples like

```ts
interface Counter {
  (start: number): string;
  interval: number;
  reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
  let counter = <Counter>function (start: number) { };
  counter.interval = 123;
  counter.reset = function () { };
  return counter;
}
```

and

```ts
interface Square extends Shape, PenStroke {
  sideLength: number;
}
  
let square = <Square>{};
```

I am having trouble understanding what this exactly means or the way to think of/understand it.

Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: I found this question looking for a more comprehensive understanding of angle brackets in Typescript, and this question provides information on more uses for angle brackets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369249/6691051

Answer (score 140, accepted):

That's called [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or casting.

These are the same:

```
let square = <Square>{};
let square = {} as Square;
```

Example:

```
interface Props {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    name: string;
}

let a = {};
a.x = 3; // error: Property 'x' does not exist on type `{}`
```

So you can do:

```
let a = {} as Props;
a.x = 3;
```

Or:

```
let a = <Props> {};
```

Which will do the same

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is possible to do this in interface definitions? For example:- `interface Person { name: string; age: number;} interface Call {(person as Person) : boolean;}`

Comment: No, casting is done at runtime, and interface/class definitions are static. It should be: `interface Call { (person: Person) : boolean; }`

Comment: let a: Props = {}; is giving me error. "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Props'." , don't know why.

Comment: @Md.NahiduzzamanRose Yeah, you'll need to do: `let a = {} as Props;`. The compiler tells you that the value you used lacks the properties which are defined in `Props`. Using type assertion you can tell the compiler that you "know better".

Comment: It is not casting.

Comment: WOW what  a nice explanation!

Comment: Typescript is a transpiled, not compiled, so essentially all that happens is a conversation to JavaScript. There is no casting at runtime and both {} as Type and <Type>{} have the same output which is {}. This is typecasting purely to let the transpiler know that you, as the developer, are confident in knowing the type that it can’t imply.

Comment: Maybe someone will ask about why there are `<Props>` and `as Props`, in .tsx when you use JSX syntax the angle bracket might be misinterpreted as component, so in jsx use `as Props`.

Comment: will let a =<Any> {} work?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work   'Props' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)

Answer (score 14):

This is called [Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion).

You can read about it in [Basarat's "TypeScript Deep Dive"](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion), or in the [official TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

You can also watch this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPuk5gDXzoo) for a nice introduction.

Comment: Thanks. was about to post the answer myself. But as a follow up, is it possible to do this in function parameters when using interfaces?

Comment: Unfortunately the first link is broken as of now.