# I can't understand the syntax: (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance)

Tags: angular, components, angular5

I am studying how to create a component dynamically in Angular. I can't understand the syntax:

```
(<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
```

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does enclosing a class in angle brackets "<>" mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831342/what-does-enclosing-a-class-in-angle-brackets-mean-in-typescript)

Comment: Check out this doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

With this line `(<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;`

In fact you tell to TS the instance is type of `AdComponent` it's only this.

So in your components who is loaded dynamically the `@Input() data` is a `AdComponent`
like this

```
@Input() data:AdComponent
```