# Why and when should I use TypeScript's "return X as Y"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

Reading a code sample that contains the code below.

```
import { Group } from '../models/Group'

export class GroupAccess {    
  constructor(
    private readonly docClient: DocumentClient = createDynamoDBClient(),
    private readonly groupsTable = process.env.GROUPS_TABLE) {
  }
  async getAllGroups(): Promise<Group[]> {
    console.log('Getting all groups')

    const result = await this.docClient.scan({
      TableName: this.groupsTable
    }).promise()

    const items = result.Items
    return items as Group[]
  }
 ...
```

content in the ../models/Group

```
export interface Group {
  id: string
  name: string
  description: string
  userId: string
  timestamp: string
}
```

Q:

items is an AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentList.ItemList. Is the code below trying to typecast to Group[]? The syntax looks different from the regular type conversion https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

```
return items as Group[]
```

Comment: `as` is [TypeScript syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), not JavaScript

Comment: Using other then basit javascript types looks like typescript, not plain javascript. Isn't it?

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks. Updated the tags..Are you referring to "And the other is the as-syntax:

let someValue: any = "this is a string";

let strLength: number = (someValue as string).length;
The two samples are equivalent. Using one over the other is mostly a choice of preference; however, when using TypeScript with JSX, only as-style assertions are allowed."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does enclosing a class in angle brackets "<>" mean in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831342/what-does-enclosing-a-class-in-angle-brackets-mean-in-typescript)

Comment: Also relevant: [Any difference between type assertions and the newer `as` operator in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33503077) - the dupe is about type assertions, this link is about the `as` style type assertion.

Comment: Thank you. So it is the syntax to type assert to an interface definition. I.e., assert items to be Group[] interface type.

Comment: @drdot yes, a type assertion is a compiler directive to tell TS "treat this **as** this thing", it's overriding the compiler derived type with what you tell it to and the compiler will accept it without question. That can be dangerous, though, since you're willingly giving away type safety for a moment. You should only do it if there is no better way to supply the compiler with some information. Because otherwise you can do `myVar = null as string` and this will make TS think `myVar` contains a string but doing `myVar.startsWith("foo")` will throw an error.