# JavaScript template-like statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I am a C++ developer and I am trying to master JavaScript. I encountered a syntax in JavaScript that I could not find any documentation about.

It is the same syntax as templates in C++. Here is an example that I got from reading the RxJs tutorials.

```
const subject = new Subject<number>();
```

Can someone explain to me what feature of the JavaScript language is that ? In C++, "Subject" would be a templated class and "number" is a type parameter.

If I google for "JavaScript template", then something else comes up such as JavaScript templated strings.

As a side note, I find JavaScript very difficult to master. I am currently reading a book "Eloquent JavaScript", I could not find any mention of that syntax above in that book. Could someone refer me some better learning material for JavaScript.

Comment: That looks like TypeScript, not JavaScript.  The angle bracket syntax is a generic.

Comment: Yeah that's TypeScript, a superset (?) of Javascript -- number would be the type

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I got that piece of code above from RxJs. I thought, that Js in RxJs meant JavaScript. Here is the link:
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject.

Comment: @RichardT TypeScript compiles to JavaScript.  Their code samples are TS, which get compiled to JS for execution in the browser.  TS is a superset of the JS syntax that gives you a type system among other things.

Comment: My opinion (not that it's worth much), if you're trying to master JavaScript, stick with using plain vanilla JavaScript (like that book is teaching you, it's actually very good) and don't jump into libraries or frameworks like React, Angular, RxJS, TypeScript, etc. until you understand why you would need to use them. Most of them are attempts to address JavaScript's perceived shortcomings or issues specific to running in web browsers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules for the use of angle brackets in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358364/rules-for-the-use-of-angle-brackets-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

That is not exactly JavaScript, that is TypeScript, and what you're seeing is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), a feature of TS only. In a nutshell (because there is a ***lot*** to uncover there), JS is not typed

```
class Subject {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = null;
  }
}

const subject = new Subject();
subject.foo = 'foo'; // ok
subject.foo = 42; // ok
```

while TS is a superset of JavaScript that allows for typing so as to catch potential errors at compile time:

```
class Subject {
  foo: number;
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 42;
  }
}

const subject = new Subject();
subject.foo = 'foo'; // invalid TS, because subject.foo must be a number, not a string
```

TS generics allow to define types in a more flexible and reusable fashion:

```
class Subject<T> {
  foo: T;
  constructor() {
    this.foo = null;
  }
}

const subject = new Subject<number>();
subject.foo = 42; // ok, because 42 is a number
subject.foo = 'foo'; // not ok, 'foo' is a string
const anotherSubject = new Subject<string>();
subject.foo = 'foo'; // ok
```