# Angular - Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular project i receive this error: `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]'`

I have a simple angular code with a helper-class making a request to url, which sends back a JSON array like `[ {a: b, c: d}, {e: f} ... ]` and everything works fine, with the expected results, but when i try to return the results to the main page.

I'd keep enforced the type, but don't know what i might need to resolve this error and want to understand it.

I'm obv open to questions about the code.

---

### HelpClass

```
export class ExampleJsonGetter{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getArray() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post<any>('https://anUrl.com/getjsonarray')
        .subscribe({
          next: data => {
            resolve(data);
          },
          error: error => {
            reject(error);
          }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

### Main Page Class

```
export class MainPage{
  variable = [];
  constructor(){
    example.getArray().then((data)=>{
/*★*/ variable = data;  /* ★ */
      console.log(variable); // on firefox: 'Array(12): ...' As expected
      console.log(typeof variable); // 'object', souldn't it be Array?
    }).catch(e=>console.error(e));
  }
}
```

---

The only way it **seems** to work is replacing `★` with `variable = new Array( ...data);`

I don't even know what those triple dots do,can you explain me?.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't get the "replacing *" part. Where are you using the `*`?

Comment: For the `typeof variable`, in JS an array is an object, so that's correct. Another way to check that a variable is an array is by `isArray()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: The 3 dots (`...`) is the spread operator, which is usually used to expand the items of an iterable object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: thanks @BrunoMonteiro for the name and the reference to isArray(), i'll need that. i also tried to make more readable the /* ★ */

Answer (score 3):

This is a `typescript` error indicating a type mismatch. Lets consider below

```
getArray() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post<any>('https://anUrl.com/getjsonarray')
        .subscribe({
          next: data => {
            resolve(data);
          },
          error: error => {
            reject(error);
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

`getArray()` will return `Promise<any>` since the line `this.http.post<any>('https://anUrl.com/getjsonarray')` returns `any`

In the main page you have `variable = [];` indicating type `any[]`. So you are trying to assign type `any` to type `any[]` which will throw error.

To solve this change the line to `this.http.post<any[]>('https://anUrl.com/getjsonarray')`

Comment: thanks, and can you link me or name what is that `fun<something>(args)` sintax with angle brackets?

Comment: this is Type Casting using the <> operator, `this.http.get<any[]>(url)` implies that the `get` function will return an `any[]`

Comment: thans, i found this looking for type casting, i link it here for future use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358364/rules-for-the-use-of-angle-brackets-in-typescript#37369249

Comment: i just applied your correction, unfortunately it doesn't work, what can i do?

Comment: yes. `data.forEach()` works, so i tried pushing values into an array, which once logged seems to be undefined (throwing an error). maybe the problem is more than just the data itself and it's me with the wrong grammar. suggestions? meanwhile i'm going to read more about how to use arays [here: Typescript Spec on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/28840863a635b6803505a821bcb18d9638c38012/doc/spec.md) and [Here: typescript microsoft handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org)

Answer (score 1):

It is best if you'll use either `Subscription` or `Promise` not combining them in a single http call.

**Helper**

```
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


export class ExampleJsonGetter {
   ...
   getArray(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http
       .post<any>('https://anUrl.com/getjsonarray')
       .pipe(catchError(err => throwError(err)))              // Catch and throw error

   }
}
```

If the above endpoint sends an `object` instead of an `array`, you can convert the response to an array by adding this to your pipe

```
import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

```
getArray(): Observable<any[]> {                   // Now in any[] type
  return this.http
     .post<any>('https://anUrl.com/getjsonarray')
     .pipe(
       toArray(),                                // Add this
       catchError(err => throwError(err))
     )             
}
```

**MainPage**

```
example
  .getArray()
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log(data, Array.isArray(data))      // Check the data and confirm if it's an array
    err => console.error(err)                           // Console any error if there's any

  )
```

Comment: this piping is something i've seen but never used. which topic should i look for to learn about it? i was just trying to learn observer and rxjs observables, but since i just have only one subscription i thought that promises would do a better job. (i only know promises to handle async, tight now)

Comment: Oh, I see, no problem :)
The piping is in relation to handling observables with rxjs. You can learn more in here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/ If this is quite new for you, there's no problem in resorting to promises as for now, that will also be ok :)