# What is <any> doing in the following TypeScript code?

Tags: typescript

```
export namespace MyNameSpace {
           ...
    ... much stuff ...
           ...
    [
        'item1',
        'item2'
    ].forEach(x=>{
        (<any>MyNameSpace)[x] = function (r,s,o) {
            return someFunction(x,r,s,o);
        };
    });
}
```

---

original version:

```
[
    'item1',
    'item2'
].forEach(x=>{
    (<any>MyType)[x] = function (r,s,o) {
        return someFunction(x,r,s,o);
    };
});
```

No search engine (even Stack Overflow or GitHub) returns any useful results searching for `<any>`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html, or e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37358364/3001761

Comment: Are you sure this is even valid code?

Comment: Actually in this case: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: @VLAZ It runs fine. I can't figure out what it does though...
Wild guess is it's casting MyType (which is NOT an array) as a generic `any` type then .. indexing into it (???) and assigning a function to it.   And since that's the last line in the export block, I guess it just throws it away? Of course no one saw fit to add a comment for what they were going for.

Comment: @VLAZ it is if you make it `forEach` and add the missing closing braces/parentheses. Also if `MyType` is actually a *value*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that's what I meant... I don't know if it's a type assertion or a syntax error. If OP claims it works, must be a type assertion but that is not really obvious from the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I formatted the code better and realized I hadn't grabbed the closing brackets/parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has potential bugs, a great feature of TypeScript is the fact that you can avoid [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), so use interfaces! (`<any>` is a generic type).

In your example code, `<any>` means that `MyNameSpace` is being cast to an `object` of **unknown** attributes, which means that anything you pass to `x` would be "valid".

Your code is kind of equivalent to this:

```js
MyNameSpace.item1 = function(...) { return ...}
MyNameSpace.item2 = function(...) { return ...}
```

Normally that code would return errors when `item1` and `item2` are not part of `MyNameSpace` definition, that being said... the `<any>` cast is being used to avoid that error. Is an antipattern.

One way to address this kind of need is to add the new attributes to the `MyNameSpace` definition and then add a line of code for every attribute:

```js
export interface MyType {  // <-- example interface 
    item1: () => {};
    item2: () => {};
}
MyNameSpace.item1 = function(...) { return ...}
MyNameSpace.item2 = function(...) { return ...}
```

This has the inconvenience of adding a line of code for every attribute, however, it'll save you a lot of refactoring issues in the future.

Another way to address your requirement is to use an [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), which might be easier to maintain:

```js
export enum availableItems {
    item1 = 'item1',
    item2 = 'item2',
    ...
}

export type MyType = {
    [itemKey in availableItems]: () => {}
}

// ...later you can iterate `availableItems ` enum definition which will be valid attributes
```

In a simple statement, whenever possible avoid using the generic type `<any>`. In my case, it's a burden I've always regretted doing.

Comment: I FINALLY found the doc page for what any is doing in that code. It's a type assertion https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-assertion.   At any rate, I got the interface implemented in several places to clean up bad code. Never did get the enum+list comprehension method in your last example from VLAZ to work. Also can't find docs for that `[key in array]` syntax either.

Comment: @AppFzx "*Also can't find docs for that [key in array] syntax either.*" [It's a mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)